# How to return 0 by default if column value not exists in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, subquery, sql-in

I have a table with columns `amount` and `feehead`

```
amount      feehead
4000.00     Examination_Fee
4000.00     Examination_Fee
0.00        Late_Fee_Fine
2500.00     Late_Fee_Fine
0.00        Re-Admission_Fee
0.00        Re-Admission_Fee
5500.00     Registration_Fee
5500.00     Registration_Fee
5500.00     Registration_Fee
5500.00     Registration_Fee
76500.00    Tution_Fee
84000.00    Tution_Fee
```

Now I want to sum by feehead in this query

```
select ISNULL(SUM(amount),0) as total
from tablename
where feehead in ('Admission_Fee','Examination_Fee','Financial_Assistance','Fine_Money','Graduation_Fee','Kinship','Laboratory_Fee','Library_Fee','Medical_Fee','Other','Re-Admission_Fee','Registration_Fee','Scholarship','Sports_Fee','Late_Fee_Fine','Tution_Fee')
group by feehead
```

It sums all the rows in which feehead exists in table, now I want to return 0 if feehead not exists in table

How to do this?

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? They are different products...

Comment: What do you mean by "if feehead not exists in table"? Please illustrate with sample data and expected results.

Comment: SQL Server not MySql

Comment: Please [edit] the tags then.

Comment: it return 
8000
2500
0
22000
160500

but i want like
as in feehead Admission_Fee not exists and Examination_Fee exists 
so it should return
0
8000 
.......
and so on for all feehead

Comment: You'll need a table of possible values for `feehead`, and then left join that table to your current one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option enumerates the values as rows in a derived table, then brings the table with a `left join`:

```
select f.feehead, coalesce(t.sum_amount, 0) sum_amount
from (values 
    ('Admission_Fee'),
    ('Examination_Fee'),
    ('Financial_Assistance'),
    ...
) f(feehead)
left join (
    select feehead, sum(amount) sum_amount
    from mytable 
    group by feehead
) t
on t.feehead = f.feehead
group by f.feehead
```

You can also use a lateral join, or a subquery:

```
select 
    f.feehead,   
    (
        select coalesce(sum(t.amount), 0) 
        from mytable t
        where t.feehead = f.feehead
    ) sum_amount
from (values 
    ('Admission_Fee'),
    ('Examination_Fee'),
    ('Financial_Assistance'),
    ...
) f(feehead)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have a table containing all possible feehead, you can LEFT JOIN like shown below. This will give you all feeheads that do not have a value and those that do.

```
select f.feehead, ISNULL(SUM(amount),0) as total
from table_with_all_feehead f left join tablename t on t.feehead = f.feehead
group by f.feehead
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to put all of your feehead's into a separate table (not just list all of them out in your WHERE clause).

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3d9776/1/0)

Setup

```
CREATE TABLE tablename
(
    amount INT,
    feehead VARCHAR(250)
)
INSERT INTO tablename VALUES(4000, 'Examination_Fee')
INSERT INTO tablename VALUES(4000, 'Examination_Fee')
INSERT INTO tablename VALUES(25, 'Late_Fee')
INSERT INTO tablename VALUES(0, 'Late_Fee')


CREATE TABLE feeheads( fee_nm VARCHAR(250) ) 

INSERT INTO feeheads
VALUES
  ('Examination_Fee'),
  ('Late_Fee'),
  ('Registration_Fee')
```

Use case

```
SELECT
  ISNULL(SUM(t.amount), 0) AS total,
  f.fee_nm
FROM
  feeheads f
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  tablename t ON t.feehead = f.fee_nm
GROUP BY
  f.fee_nm
    enter code here
```

Outputs
[image]